# Images crawled by python from website cannot be open by photoshop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The webpage is like:

```
<img data-s="300,640" data-type="jpeg" data-src="http://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz/2ibL1hUwSYSJO5BkyCQMicnPL5y1yAkcKh3YCITccD4IxWibI2wKpgYatDXgBBvOW01oOnGZGPVmfMDR0cQKSjeew/0?wx_fmt=jpeg" data-ratio="1.7613636363636365" data-w="440" width="auto" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box !important; word-wrap: break-word !important; width: auto !important; visibility: visible !important; height: auto !important;" _width="auto" src="http://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz/2ibL1hUwSYSJO5BkyCQMicnPL5y1yAkcKh3YCITccD4IxWibI2wKpgYatDXgBBvOW01oOnGZGPVmfMDR0cQKSjeew/640?wx_fmt=jpeg&amp;tp=webp&amp;wxfrom=5&amp;wx_lazy=1">
```

so my script to download the image:

```
    imgs =  soup.find_all('img')
    for img in imgs:
        if img != None and img['data-type']=="jpeg":
            count += 1
            link = img['data-src']
            piccode = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
            picname = "pic"+str(count)+".jpg"
            with open(picname,'wb') as code:
                code.write(piccode)
```

But the jpg file that I download cannot be opened or edited by photoshop. Somehow I fill that the iamges I download are borken.Why?

Comment: what is the url of the webpage?

Comment: http://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzA3NDAxOTM5Mw==&mid=211407063&idx=3&sn=14bf51d1ab1c3153f00167228b039fd3&scene=23&srcid=JYeuAIfN0fogamGULT24#rd

Comment: What is the actual complete filename of the downloaded file?  The first file on that page is "640.jpeg" and can be opened when downloaded manually.  However looking at the source beautiful soup might be saving it as simply "640" instead of "640.jpeg" which photoshop might be having a problem with.

Comment: Have you tried any photoshop related fixes? For instance, there is [this solution](http://www.solidairweb.com/blog-website-design-chester/2010/09/cant-edit-a-gif-or-jpg-file-in-photoshop/) for issues with opening `.jpg` and `.gif` in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

Make sure that the saved files are being set with correct permissions.

**Then**

I can't answer the question of "Why can't photoshop open your pictures." but I can offer an alternative which worked for me. It's below.

It looks like `urllib` has a built in function that downloads and saves a file in a single line. Not sure if urllib2 does but I couldn't find anything quickly.

Replace

```
piccode = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
```

With

```
urllib.urlretrieve(link, pic_filename)
```

You'll also be able to get rid of the code that comes after this line since `urlretrieve` does this all in one line.

Let me know if this works and if you need anymore help!

Comment: It's realy a nice improve of my code, thanks. The image still cannot be open by photoshop. Maybe it's the source that is broken?

Comment: Try going to the site, right clicking on the image, and saving it. Then, open it up with photoshop and see if you have the same issue.